# UnZip sqlite на sd андроид

Tags: java, android, sqlite, zip

Есть андроид приложение с довольно большой SQLite, хранимой в ресурсах в zip архиве, при распаковке этим методом:

```
private void copyFromZipFile() throws IOException{
    InputStream is = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.recipe_db);
    File DB_PATH = context.getExternalCacheDir();
    File outFile = new File(DB_PATH , "recipe_db");
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFile.getAbsolutePath());
    ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(is));
    try {
        ZipEntry ze;
        while ((ze = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) {
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int count;
            while ((count = zis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                baos.write(buffer, 0, count);
            }
            baos.writeTo(myOutput);
        }
    } finally {
        zis.close();
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        is.close();
    }
}
```

Но на устройствах с малым количеством оперативки выскакивает ошибка:

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError 
>   java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.expand(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:91) 
>   java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:201) 
>   com.iammaksimus.recipes.MainModel.copyFromZipFile(MainModel.java:93)

как с этим бороться?

Comment: Попробуй записать базу, в zip-архив,  несколькими файлами определенного размера.

Comment: я думал об этом, пока что увеличил размер буффера в 8 раз, вроде как работает, но не очень надежно на мой взгляд

Comment: а смысл в использование `ByteArrayOutputStream`? Пишите сразу в `myOutput`.

Comment: ДА, все заработало) спасибо за помощь)